# wrong json string manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, json, amazon-ec2

I have created one page which takes data from table `view_name` and shows chart using google graph API.
When I run the system on my localhost, it gives correct results and shows chart.

When I created same database and took same files on my ec2 linux isntance, everything else works fine just graph is not appearing. I checked `firebug` result it show that `json string` coming in localhost took correct data while on ec2 instance json string is false.

json string while I run on localhost:
`{"cols":[{"label":"pcount","type":"string"},{"label":"ncount","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"pcount"},{"v":179}]},{"c":[{"v":"ncount"},{"v":237}]}]}`

json string while I run on ec2 instance:
`{"cols":[{"label":"pcount","type":"string"},{"label":"ncount","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}`

my table is:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ind_type | Index_val |
+----------+-----------+
| pcount   |       179 |
| ncount   |       237 |          which is same on localhost and ec2 instance.
+----------+-----------+
```

my php page url.php which contains GUI button :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>ThenWat</title>

    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);    


    function drawVisualization(dataFromAjax) {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "ajax_graph_temp.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var options = {
           title: 'Index analysis',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('txtHint'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
         }
function makeAjaxCall() {
      $.ajax({url:'url.php',
              data: {},
              success: function(responseData) {
                         drawVisualization();
                       }
        });
    }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body style="height: 560px">
         <div style="z-index: 1; left: 660px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px"> 
            <button onclick="makeAjaxCall(); return false;" value="View Graph" > View Graph </button>
         </div>

         <div id="txtHint" style="z-index: 1; left: 220px; top: 250px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">        
         </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

and ajax_graph_temp.php call in ajax call is:

```
<?php
$mysqli =mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM view_name');

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'pcount', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'ncount', 'type' => 'number')
);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {
      $temp = array();
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ind_type']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Index_val']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
//$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Everything is same on both localhost and ec2 instance. Where can be the issue? Do I making any mistake anywhere?

Comment: What's `url.php` doing?

Comment: Looks to me like the table you're reading on te EC2 version doesn't have the right data in it, or you're reading the wrong table.

Comment: @AmalMurali: it's first file which contains gui, button to click. See again I added the name

Comment: @MikeW: thank, i also though same, but I checked table name both are same. Infact I copied same file. And also tables contains data same as I have mentioned. I know there could not be magic! But i dont know where the mistake has been hidden..

Comment: which versions of php are you running in each environment?

Comment: @datasage: Does it make any difference? On my localhost its `PHP Version 5.4.16` and on ec2 instance `PHP Version 5.3.8`